# Duplicates in memory when using 'getter' functions in Fortran

Tags: oop, memory, fortran

Let's say I have an object containing a number of large arrays

```
type, public :: MyObject
  implicit none
  real*8, allocatable, private :: array1, array2, ... etc
contains
  procedure :: get_array1, get_array2, ... etc
end type MyObject
```

as well as 'getter' functions

```
function get_array1(self) result(array1)
  implicit none
  class(MyObject), intent(in) :: self
  real, dimension(size(self%array1)) :: array1

  array1 = self%array1
end function get_array1
```

If I use the getter function in a program as follows

```
somearray = MyObject%get_array1()
```

then I will end up with the values in `array1` stored both in `MyObject` and in `somearray`, which is wasteful. If however I directly pass the result of `get_array1` to another subroutine:

```
call a_subroutine(arg1, arg2, MyObject%get_array1())
```

or if I refer to it directly in the main program without assigning it to a new array:

```
a_sum = sum(a_vector(:)*MyObject%get_array1())
```

am I going to end up with multiples copies of array1 stored in memory? Or will the memory containing the function return value be freed after the subroutine call or the summation?

Comment: Are you asking whether a temporary array is created, or whether if one is created that it lives longer than necessary?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer. I'm asking if the temporary array will live longer than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed really likely that a temporary will be created for the array product in

```
a_sum = sum(a_vector(:)*MyObject%get_array1())
```

Because `sum` is intrisic, soe compilers may be able to optimize it, but in general a temporary is likely.

Such temporaries are created at the call site and destroyed after the call. They may be placed on the stack or on the heap depending on the compiler, its setttings and the array size.

You shouldn't worry that the array will live for too long after the call.